# Why does C++ have an ostream overloading issue with customised struct vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I have written a code which has to iterate through a vector and print its contents. I am getting an error:

> dfs.cpp:45:16: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘const traits’)
>      std::cout << *c << ' ';
>   dfs.cpp:44:15: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’
>      std::cout<<*v<

However, the iteration works for a vector of type *char*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct traits
{
    int x;
    bool visit;
    std::list<int> friends;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of employees: " << endl;
    int noOfEmployees, noOfFriends;
    cin>>noOfEmployees;
    std::vector<traits> employees;
    int i = 0; int j;
    while(noOfEmployees--){
        traits v;
        v.x = i;
        cout << "Enter the no of friends: " << endl;
        cin >> noOfFriends;
        while(noOfFriends--){
            cin>>j;
            v.friends.push_back(j);
        }
        v.visit = false;
        employees.push_back(v);
    }

    std::vector<char> path;
    path.push_back('a');
    path.push_back('l');
    path.push_back('i');
    path.push_back('a');
    for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = path.begin(); i != path.end(); ++i){
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    for(std::vector<traits>::iterator v = employees.begin(); v != employees.end(); ++v){
        std::cout<<*v<<endl;
    }
}
```

I have seen few answers but I want to do this without operator overloading, what would be the correct or more *C++-nic* way?

Comment: You need to overload `operator<<` for `traits`, or print out the content of `traits` by yourself.

Comment: Why would there exist a built-in `operator<<` for a type you just created? `char` is part of the language, of course printing it would be supported out of the box.

Comment: One does not exist for the standard containers, you have to write an overload for yourself.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to give code that works and provide an error message for code that you do not show. Please provide an [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error your getting is telling you that the ostream operator doesn't have a rule to apply to objects of type `trait`.  The most "C++nic" way to do this would be to overload the `<<` operator, but you've said that you don't want to do that.

Given that constraint, your can translate the  `traits` item into something the ostream operator supports.  A reasonable way to do this would be with a namespace level, non-member function

```
std::string to_string(const traits& t) {
/// Code to generate a string representation of your traits object
}
for (const auto emp& : employees){
    std::cout<< to_string(emp) << ' ';
}
```

If I saw code like this in production I would expect the author had a reason not to use the more canonical operator overload, and I'd be disappointed if they did not.

Comment: "nic" is definitely not the suffix to use here.  Getting caught up trying too hard to mimic the word pythonic?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `iostream operators` `<<` & `>>` for `istream` and `ostream` either it be for `cout` and `cin` or `ifstream`, `ofstream` or `fstream` objects think of it in the manner of the compiler or one who is writing the compiler...

These are template types. A user will create a template with a various number of types that could be built in or custom user defined. To give this kind of power to the user how would the compiler know if the `ostream` in your case that will be using a `list` is a `list<int>`, `list<float>`, `list<yourType>`? So you have to create the overload yourself for all the types that you want to support the `operator>>()` and `operator<<()`. And as user Spacemoose beat me to it; you would have to convert the underlying type via stand a lone function to a type that already works with the operators.